# Keeping the contents of tables from one class to another class in java

Tags: java

I want to use a table already filled in a first class and keep  the content of the table to make changes in a second class

ClassA:

```
public class ClassA {

public String catas[][]=new String[100][100];
public  int type[][]=new int[100][100];

//code lines

public int createInitBlocr1 (StringBuffer sb, Node trn, int y, Object[] a)
{

            //code lines

            catas[y][f]=trn.getName();  
            type[y][f]=trn.getType();
}

public int[][] getType(){
     return type;
}

 public String[][] getCatas(){
     return catas;
 }
}
```

ClassB:

```
public class ClassB extends JFrame {


ClassA c = new ClassA();

String[][] nom = c.getCatas();
int[][] nom = c.getType();

private void jbInit() throws Exception {

    //using the content of tables and make changes

}

}
```

My problem is in ClassB I have tow empty tables not the same content I have in ClassA

Comment: you called `ClassA a = new ClassA();` but never call `a.createInitBlocr1();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure your question.  You want copies of ClassA's arrays in ClassB?

Use System.arrayCopy()

otherwise B's arrays will just be references to A's.

Comment: thanks a lot, I think that's  exactly what I need: reference of ClassA's arrays, but how can I use System.arrayCopy()?

Comment: With arrayCopy you are getting two arrays (two references) with the same data: a copy&paste memory allocation

Comment: Check javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29

Answer (score 0):

In ClassB, after `ClassA c = new ClassA()`, you should call `c.createInitBlocr1(...)`. Then `c.getCatas()` and `c.getType()` will return the instances you are looking for: always the same instances.

Comment: Here you are getting two references to the same data